# Sorting and Querying an Encrypted MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, encryption

2 queries regarding encrypted/decrypted values from a MySQL table.

1) How can I possible sort these, since as the values are encrypted ORDER BY is out, and JavaScript won't sort a) correctly and b) at all. Code below, excuse formatting.

2) How would I query 'between values'

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>

<body>
  <table>
      <tr>
<?php
// Connects to Server, queries all on that table.
$db_connect=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("Sorry, Poor or No Connection");
$db_found=mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Sorry, Cannot Connect to Database");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");

// Creates Table to be used
echo "
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // Decrypts table IDs
  $dec_FName = decrypt($row['FName'],'SECUREKEY');
  $dec_LName = decrypt($row['LName'],'SECUREKEY');

  echo "<tr>";
    <echo>"<td>" . $dec_FName . "</td>";
    <echo>"<td>" . $dec_LName . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  mysql_close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I Suspect an array needs to be created. I'm happy to use JavaScript, PHP or anything else you can recommend.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me:

```
$q3='SELECT users.uid,
users.vr,
users.br,
AES_DECRYPT(users.nm1,"123") AS nm1,
AES_DECRYPT(users.nm2,"123") AS nm2,
AES_DECRYPT(users.nm3,"123") AS nm3,
ussys.ty1,
ussys.ty3
FROM users,ussys WHERE users.uid=ussys.uid
ORDER BY nm1 DESC
';
```

It sorts nicely on nm1, giving me Zack-Willeke-Victor-Roiwan-Plop-Kwab-Krab-Karel-Johannes-Harry-Gerard-Dirk-Cornelis-Bernard-Anton as a result.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this in the SQL server. If the columns are all encrypted, there's no way it can sort or filter on the columns in a meaningful way.

You'll need to pull the data into your PHP and sort it there. You'll be able to use any of PHP's [array handling functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), or your own, once you've decrypted the data.

Obviously with large data sets this becomes unwieldly pretty quick, as you need to retrieve all the data for each use. Perhaps you can store some data unencrypted for this purpose, but clearly that's very specific to your security needs.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is quite old, but I came across the same issue and there isn't really much info out there about this.  This is what I did and it works like magic.

```
 SELECT AES_DECRYPT(column1, '%key%') AS 'column1' FROM `myTable` WHERE
 1 ORDER BY AES_DECRYPT(column1, '%key%') ASC;
```

I have a table with 230 rows and 4 columns to decrypt plus the sorting column and it takes 2.5 miliseconds to reutrn the results on a VPS VM with these specs: 2 Xeon E5 CPU Cores, 2 GBs of RAM, 50 GBs SSD.